# java regex issue, how to fix this

Tags: java, regex

```
String pattern = "\\b(\\w+)[&|\\/| ][\\w+]*";
```

`Test String: val
Hello/ World - fail
Hello/World - pass
Hello&World - pass
Hello World - pass
Hello World/ World - fail`

```
if(val.matches(pattern)){
   //do something
}
```

First & last pattern `Hello/ World` & `Hello World/ World` is failing, am I missing something in my regex?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: `|` in `[]` does not do what you think it does. it is one of the characters that can be matched, so `Hello|World` would be matched. You probably just want to leave it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
\\b(\\w+)[&\\/ ]+\\w+

                 ^^
```

That quantifier fixes it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/23

The problem with your `failed` case is `/` .You have `2` characters but you are capturing only `1` thru the character class.Add a quantifier `+` to make it match all.

For the new question use

```
\b(\w+)([&\\\/ ]+\w+)+\b
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/25

Comment: Adding `+' fixes the issue, Thanks !

Comment: @vks you need to remove the in-between pipe symbol.

Comment: @vks There is another test case: `Hello World/ World`, this one doesn't work too

Comment: @user525146 You should have mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: @user525146 that would need an entire new regex.See https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/25